# Why does my card rotate in the opposite direction first when I try to rotate in a different axis?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a simple card flipper and right now I can flip the cards up, down, left, and right.
What does work:

- I can flip the card up and down as much as I want and it works as expected; same for left and right

What *doesn't* work:

- Sometimes different combinations of the flips doesn't work as expected and I'm not sure what the issue is

Trying it out will really help illustrate the issue!

I tried to create a class for each direction, rotating in the negative and positive x and y axis, and toggling the class on button click but I don't want to have to remove the transform before I flip on the other axis. Now, I have a value for the degrees in the x and y direction which I add to or subtract from on each button click so that I can keep flipping, but that also has its issues.

**Edit**: For example, if I click "up" once, and then "left", I expect the card to flip up on the x-axis and then left on the y-axis. When I click "up", it flips up, but when I click on "left", it flips down first and then I have to click on "left" again to flip it properly.

```js
let upBtn = document.getElementById("top");
let dnBtn = document.getElementById("down");
let lftBtn = document.getElementById("left");
let rtBtn = document.getElementById("right");
let card = document.querySelector(".card");

let degreesX = 0;
let degreesY = 0;


function toggleDir(dir) {
  switch (dir) {
    case "up":
      degreesX += 180;
      card.style = `transform: rotateX(${degreesX}deg)`;

      break;
    case "down":
      degreesX -= 180;
      card.style = `transform: rotateX(${degreesX}deg)`;
      break;
    case "right":
      degreesY -= 180;
      card.style = `transform: rotateY(${degreesY}deg)`;
      break;
    case "left":
      degreesY += 180;
      card.style = `transform: rotateY(${degreesY}deg)`;
      break;
    case "reset":
      card.style = `transform: rotate(0deg)`;
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, hsl(189, 100%, 44%, 0.62), hsla(194, 100%, 28%, 0.62));
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1500ms;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cardUp {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.cardDown {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.cardLeft {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.cardRight {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.reset {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.front,
.back {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/350x500);
}

.back {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=123/350x500);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front"></div>
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="top" onclick="toggleDir('up')">top</button>
  <button id="down" onclick="toggleDir('down')">down</button>
  <button id="left" onclick="toggleDir('left')">left</button>
  <button id="right" onclick="toggleDir('right')">right</button>
  <button id="left" onclick="toggleDir('reset')">reset</button>
</body>
```

Comment: could you give us an example of a combination that doesn't work?

Comment: Sure! I just added it to the question as an edit

Comment: Instead of using codepen, include a Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet from the editor (Ctrl+M).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're 2 causes here:

- Every time you flip to new direction, your previous `transform` is overridden by the new one.
- You only have 1 variable to track the degrees of both directions (`x-axis` & `y-axis`)

---

According to that, you need to do 2 things:

- Keep the latest value of the card's `transform`.

  For example, first you flip up --> `transform: rotateX(180deg);`, then you flip left --*expect*--> `transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg);`. But according to the code, here we only have `transform: rotateY(180deg);`.
- Separate 2 variables `degreesX` and `degreesY` to track each direction.

---

You can see the code solution [here](https://codepen.io/haptn1/pen/GRXjxxL).

In that code, I checked if the previous `transform` already had value of the direction, then replace the old value by the newer one (using **regex** to replace). Otherwise, just set the value to `transform`.

Hope this solve your problem!

Comment: Interesting. I previously had two variables for the x and y directions, but it didn't do the trick. I didn't track the transform though so I'll try that!

Comment: Just added my code changes to my question! Still not working as expected but I think it might be something really simple that I'm missing.

Comment: It's still not working as expected maybe due to the 1st reason, the latest transform was not kept. For example, first you flip up --> `transform: rotateX(180deg);`, then you flip left --expect--> `transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg);`. But according to the code, here we only have `transform: rotateY(180deg);`. So I think that's the problem.

I'll make it a try ^^ I'll back when finish this.

Comment: Hi, I've just updated my answer with the solution & explanation above.

Comment: This is amazing! Exactly how I expect it to work thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

in your function toggleDir() degrees is not defined, use degreesX or degreesY

Comment: Ah, I actually initialized it to zero outside of the function and then I increment the rotation on the axis depending on the button. Didn't get an error when I ran it though.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a partial solution to your problem, this is just a base to which you can build from and find better solutions.

`html` Added two separate cards `CardX` and `CardY`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cardY">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cardX">
            <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back"></div>
        </div>

      
    </div>
  
    <button id="top" onclick="toggleDir('up')">up</button>
    <button id="down" onclick="toggleDir('down')">down</button>
    <button id="left" onclick="toggleDir('left')">left</button>
    <button id="right" onclick="toggleDir('right')">right</button>
    <button id="left" onclick="toggleDir('reset')">reset</button>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`css` added `position: absolute` to the cards

```
  .cardX {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* Made this card absolute so it floats on top of the other one */
    position: absolute; 
    transition: transform 1500ms;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  }
  
  .cardY {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* Made this card absolute so it floats on top of the other one */
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 1500ms;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
```

This is the same styling you had in your code just position is different

`js` Manipulated the styles of the two cards to get the rotation effect

```
let upBtn = document.getElementById("top");
let dnBtn = document.getElementById("down");
let lftBtn = document.getElementById("left");
let rtBtn = document.getElementById("right");

// Added these two
let cardX = document.querySelector(".cardX");
let cardY = document.querySelector(".cardY");


let degreesX = 0
let degreesY = 0

function toggleDir(dir) {

  switch (dir) {
    
    case "up":
      degreesX += 180
    
      cardX.style = `transform: rotateX(${degreesX}deg)`

      //Set the other card to invisible while rotating the other
      cardY.style.opacity = 0
  
      break;
    case "down":
      degreesX -= 180;
      cardX.style = `transform: rotateX(${degreesX}deg)`;

       //Set the other card to invisible while rotating the other
      cardY.style.opacity = 0
    
      break;
    case "right":
     
      degreesY += 180;
      cardY.style = `transform: rotateY(${degreesY}deg)`

       //Set the other card to invisible while rotating the other
      cardX.style.opacity = 0
      
      break;
    case "left":
      
      degreesY -= 180;
      cardY.style = `transform: rotateY(${degreesY}deg)`

       //Set the other card to invisible while rotating the other
      cardX.style.opacity = 0

      break;

  }
}
```

Problem with this solution is the images make it visible when the two card interchange what I would suggest is you find a way to add a new image on every rotation, that way everything will flow into each other.

Comment: This is an interesting way to do it as well. I'll give it a try.